# Craig Interpolation API

Tags: z3

There are versions of the Z3 SMT solver that support Craig interpolation. Methods of the API where, for example, Z3_interpolate, Z3_write_interpolation_problem, or Z3_mk_interpolation_context.

Microsoft Research provides a website with the description of the [Z3 C API](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html)! The methods that are listed above cannot be found in this documentation. Have this methods been removed? Can they be found in a specific branch of Z3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is for the `master` branch of Z3, newer features are available in the `unstable` branch, which will become the new master soon.

Comment: This release happened yesterday (v4.3.2). The master branch now contains the interpolation API as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code can be found (as of today; the code changes very frequently) in the branch "opt". The  API functions were moved from z3_api.h to z3_interp.h. It is unclear whether the code will stay in this place or not.